# how to change the ckeditor's skin in angular2

Tags: angular, ckeditor, skin

In the documentation http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_skins they are saying to pass the skin in config so i'm doing like this to pass the skin config

```
this.config = {
      skin: 'office2013'
}
```

but it''s giving me `GET http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full/skins/office2013/editor.css/` this error. How to add skin for angular2 ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own ckeditor package, put in into your project folder and include in index.html `<script src=RELPATH/ckeditor/ckeditor.js></scr>`